# Check if a spinlock was held, in a core dump

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to analyze a spinlock variable inside a core dump for Linux kernel. In case of mutex, If the mutex was locked, the count variable should be having a value of 0. In case of spinlock, spinlock_t my_lock has fields like

```
(struct raw_spinlock) rlock
      (arch_spinlock_t) raw_lock
            (unsigned int) lock 
      (unsigned int) break_lock
```

The integer variables has a value of 0. Will there be a different value in these if the lock was taken? Is there any other way of checking in the dump of a spin lock variable to see if it was taken? Is the value architecture dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a call to die(), I have collected a core dump and checked the status of die_lock spinlock variable which is locked in traps.c when die() happens. The value of lock was 1 in the locked case. This gives some clarity.

But there has been locks with large integer values as well. Still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use spin_is_locked()

(defined in spinlock.h)

Comment: I guess you read the question wrong. It is not about checking a spin lock status in a live system. This is in a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

It will have a different value if the lock is taken. You can check using spin_is_locked() from the code.
But as you are analysing dump, check how spin_lock() is implemented. It will give info about how the lock is checked and acquired. Ofcourse the spin_lock() is architecture dependent code, still the logic is same.